# SharpDX How To Render a 3D Environment

Tags: vb.net, matrix, 3d, directx, sharpdx

I just started coding some basics in SharpDX (VB.net) and I already got it to Render a 2D triangle. And I know how to render other 2D stuff, but I want to create something in 3D where I'm able to rotate the camera around some cubes. I tried it, but failed at converting the 3D Space to screen coordinates. Now Here are my Questions:

- How can I calculate a Matrix for Perspective projection?
- How can I pass that Matrix to my Vertex Shader
- How can I make the Camera rotate around the Objects when I drag the mouse over the screen?

Please explain these things to me and give some code examples. I'm just a Beginner in SharpDX and everything I found was just not understandable for me.

Comment: People are always happy to explain, but people on StackOverflow don't usually write code samples for people, not for free anyway ;P

Comment: I meant some short examples not an entire project XD. If you look around stackoverflow you'll find tons of code examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things you can do when you first start.

Firstly, there are some great examples you can leverage (Even in c# but you need VB) that you can use to learn from.

I suggest you look at this within the Sharpdx repository.  [Sharpdx direct 3d 11 samples](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/Desktop/Direct3D11)

Within these examples (especially triangle example), it goes through the basics including setting up the device, the creation of simple resources to bind to your GPU and compiling the bytecode.

The samples though use the effects methodology, which is deprecated and as such once you become familiar with compiling code, I would advise moving away from this paradigm.

The more advanced examples will show you how to set up your matrices.

The last item you wanted to know about is mouse movement.  I would advise just having a look at MSDN around mousemove events. You will need to bind one to your window/control and then read the deltas.  Use those deltas to create your rotation/movement based upon this.  Look into Vector3 (sharpdx), basically, you need to do this all in vector space and then create the various translation/rotation matrices from this.

Hope this is start.